# How to run a main method from a Kotlin class in a gradle project?

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

Some time ago I created a gradle-based project in IntelliJ to play around. I added a few Kotlin and java classes in "main", and a single java class in "test".

Now IntelliJ suggests that I can run that test class. But there is no option to "run" a new Kotlin main() that I just added in a new .kt file in the main section.

Things compile fine, but no indication whatsoever that I could "run" that main method.

I see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44615237/how-to-run-kotlin-function-in-intellij-idea), but that is for a pure Kotlin project.

I had a look into "Run/Debug" configurations. In the templates, there is one Kotlin. When I use that, I can use the file chooser to look at my Kotlin classes; down to the main method. But the "OK" button is disabled, so I can't select anything as "run" target.

I figured that I can run one of my java classes by adding this task

```
task execute(type:JavaExec) {
    main = 'com.whatever.Hello'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

and then I can run `gradle[execute]`. But When I point main to one of my Kotlin classes, I get

> Task :execute FAILED
>
> Error: Could not find or load main class com.whatever.TheKotlinClass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set `main = 'com.whatever.TheKotlinClassKt'`. The Kotlin compiler changes the name of compiled classes.

See for more details: [What is the reason for using “Kt” suffix in Kotlin classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45505169/what-is-the-reason-for-using-kt-suffix-in-kotlin-classes)

Comment: For me, there was a bit more to it (which I will add in my own answer), but your input had (in the end) the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial / error, I figured that my gradle script was missing various important things. Besides that, I also had forgotten to mark the *kotlin* folder as "source folder" in IntelliJ (as the second answer on the SO question linked in my question suggests to do).

For reference, here is a working version of my gradle script:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.31'
}

version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.+"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common"
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

task execute(type:JavaExec) {
    main = 'com.whatever.TheKotlinClassKt'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

And, side note: as soon as I found out how to *correctly* compile the Kotlin files within the gradle project ... the IntelliJ IDE also shows the "Run" button for every Kotlin class with a main().

Comment: as you created your project some time ago... maybe you want to create a new one and check the "Kotlin DSL build script"-checkbox? (of course, that wouldn't have solved your problem... but you get type safety in your build script if you want ;-))

Comment: @Roland Can I add that somehow to my existing project?

Comment: yes, at least by hand ;-) it's named `build.gradle.kts` and everything in there is Kotlin... in the end it also looks very similar to the `build.gradle` itself... I would probably just generate a single project with the kotlin dsl enabled and use that `build.gradle.kts` as a blue-print...

Comment: actually I find that problem/behaviour quite ~special... if you just start a new project/module all files in `src/main/kotlin/` or `src/main/java/` usually are directly runnable... the same with the `test`-counterpart... the other topic is gradle itself... maybe a tag regarding it might be worth it... what I also wondered is, that you needed to specify that it's a source folder.. that isn't really necessary usually... so: if I don't really understand why a certain error happens and why that answer then lead to the solution, it's also hard to upvote it... (at least for me)

Comment: regarding the accepted answer... actually... without seeing your file containing the `main` there is still a chance, that what you have written could be correct, e.g.: using something like `@file:JvmName("Hello")` in the file that contains the `main` or by placing the `main` inside an `object` with `@JvmStatic`... not that I recommend any of those... but... it could be...